# explicit instanciation of member function template in class

Tags: c++, class, templates, instance

I have a class that contains a template method declared as follow in the header:

```
Class MyClass {
public :
   template <class T>
   int memberFunction(T& arg);
}
```

the function template is defined in the .cpp as follow:

```
template<class T> int MyClass::memberFunction(T& arg){
    return arg*arg + arg + 0.2;
}
```

and instanciated in the cpp file as follow:

```
template
int MyClass::memberFunction<int>(int&);

template
int MyClass::memberFunction<double>(double&);
```

the code compiles under gcc and mscv but whenever I use the functions mscv returns a warning message demanding an explicit instanciation.
I tried to put the instanciation in the header but it throws errors, how should I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can provide an explicit instantiation declaration in the header:

```
class MyClass {
public :
   template <class T>
   int memberFunction(T& arg);
};

extern template
int MyClass::memberFunction<int>(int&);

extern template
int MyClass::memberFunction<double>(double&);
```

This explicit instantiation declaration, while not strictly needed here, may be enough to appease MSVC.

Comment: thanks ! it works. I though I could remove the instance declaration in the cpp but no. I need to read more on template mechanism.

Comment: @user2019716 - You can't remove them, they provide the definitions. This only provides declarations that somewhere there's an explicit instantiation (as you provide).

Comment: That is what I infered.

Answer (score 0):

You can define function template in header to avoid linker warnings, something like this, in myclass.h

```
class MyClass {
public :
   template <class T>
   T memberFunction(const T& arg) {
       return arg*arg + arg + 0.2;
   }
};
```

Please, note the change in declaration of template member function.
You don't need to separate declaration and definition, neither to explicitly define
specialization for int and double types, because behavior of your function is the same for int and double. Be aware of possible code bloat.
Later, you can use function, like below

```
#include "myclass.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

MyClass c1;
int res = c1.memberFunction(3);
printf("result=%d",res);
return 0;
}
```

and let compiler to deduce type of arguments and to implicitly make proper instantiation of function. If you really need ant int to return from function, you can do some casts on result.

If you really need to separate template member function declaration and definition in a way that you need to define function template member in a cpp file and to suppress linker warnings, it could be compiler dependent behaviour to deal with, if you use compiler that have depricated  export keyword you can use it or use extern keyword if supported by compiler. In that case the idea is to explicitly instantiate template function in header, that compiler has proper instantiation in a time when proccessing definitions in cpp file, or like you did to add explicit declaration on needed types in the cpp file.

Comment: I used int and double and a simple function body for the example.
I actually use more complex arguments and function body in the real project, so I needed to define the method in the cpp file and explicitly instantiate template function in header.
I found many examples but none was showing the explicit instantiation of function template.